# Equivalent of FieldTypeComponentLink in .NET?

Tags: 2009, event-system

I am trying to transfer some event system code from VB to VB.NET, and I can not determine the equivalent of `FieldTypeComponentLink`

for example

```
If objItem.FieldType = FieldTypeComponentLink Or 
   objItem.FieldType = FieldTypeMultimediaLink Then
```

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 5):

Silly me, if only i had pressed the space bar,

```
If objItem.FieldType = TDSDefines.EnumTridionWebSchemaFieldType.FieldTypeComponentLink Or 
   objItem.FieldType = TDSDefines.EnumTridionWebSchemaFieldType.FieldTypeMultimediaLink Then
```